# Edit or change or manage an existing website or web pages (which were created by a different CMS or VS asp.net ) by a new CMS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, content-management-system

If we already have a website and web pages(created by VS asp.net) can we able to edit or change or manage these by a ***new*** CMS?.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely. It may be possible to partially accomplish this via a converter tool (something that can parse the .NET site into another CMS) or a scraper tool (something that scrapes the HTML content of the live .NET site and formats it or imports it into a new CMS).

Neither of these, though, if even possible/available, will result in an exact copy of the site in another CMS.

Comment: Are you saying if we start to develop a website with a particular CMS, we need to use that CMS until the finish or even to make any changes we need to use the same particular CMS?

Comment: Well, with enough developer effort, it is always possible to port from one CMS to another. But, it'll take a lot more resources than running a simple converter or something, if that makes sense.